# GIF Speed based per computer?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, game-engine, gif

I'm working on a game engine, and want the option to play video to a jpanel or whatever. I've been trying to figure out HOW to do this, preferably using mp4, WITHOUT USING ANY 3RD PARTY SOFTWARE. The only option i've come to is using a combined gif and .wav series.

My question is, does a .gif play faster per computer? for example, if i get the movie synced perfectly on my desktop, would it have the odds of not being in sync with my laptop? would the .gif play slower/faster? If the answer is yes, how in the heck would i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it out yet? The big factor is the gif's resolution and framerate

Comment: I have, but i dont have any sources using gif AND sound together to actually see if they would go out of sync, so i didnt notice any visual difference, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are building the video in a .gif then you should be able to just take the individual images and paint them at the desired frame rate in your application without using 3rd party software.

This would allow you to sync it with your .wav for sound.

Comment: as i am fairly "noob" at this, would you maybe be able to give some example code? i really dont work with gif's a lot, so something would be helpful :) Thanks though!

Comment: @PulsePanda: StackOverflow is no code request place. If you wan't someone to write your code, you're going to have to pay him...